# file_get_html() working in localhost to load local .html files but not on host server (not on http URLs, on local .html files)

Tags: php, html, file, get

file_get_html() below working in localhost loading .html files without any issues, able to get elements using $html->find(...); .html files are under articles folder.

```
include_once 'includes/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('articles/my-first-html-file.html');
```

Same code not working on hosting server. $html simply returning blank (Neither Null nor Content)

I have tried adding "php_value allow_url_fopen On" and also making sure path from public_html as well as with fully qualified path prepending $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], but of no luck!

Above code used to work on same hosting server for past six months and this problem started all of sudden without code or configuration or s/w version changes (at least as confirmed by hosting provider)

Surprisingly `file_get_html()` not returning any error anywhere in logs too.

Also tried with file_get_contents()+str_get_html() & verified define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000); but didn't work out

WAMP on localhost and Linux on host server.
Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/845021) / Else: [How do you debug PHP scripts?](//stackoverflow.com/q/888)

Comment: @mario, it's not syntax error as the page isn't blank, can see all further output. Don't have debug environment so i used echo '=>>'.$html.'<<='; very next to above and it just displayed empty in between.Further statement $html->find('something',0) also not giving any error since $html isn't returned as Null.

Comment: `echo` isn't as useful as `var_dump` or Notices enabled.

Comment: agreed, was thinking to see entire html page as output of echo, tried var_dump($html) that returned an object holding so many arrays having their children inside something like object(simple_html_dom)#24 (23) { ["root"]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#25 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(5) ["tag"]=> string(4) "root" ["attr"]=> array(0) { } ["children"]=> array(0) { } ["nodes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(... I nowhere see any piece of content inside html tags of original source file in dump...seems it populating dom tree but with no content, i'm still scratching my head!

Comment: Ok, finally i am able to find the issue is because of server PHP version upgrade by hosting provider. Simple html dom is working without any issues up to PHP 7.0 and failed on later versions. So i set it as 7.0 in cPanel MultiPHP manager and its started working again. Posted since this information might help somebody.